# Duplicate form row in twig template symfony 4

Tags: symfony

I want to duplicate each form row inside my template by using for loop
this is my code, but it's doesn't work, it's returned only the first line with form and those other without form, please could somebody help me ?

```
{% for commande in commandes %}
<tr><td>{{ form_row(form.id, {'attr': 'value': commande.id} ) }}</td></tr>
<tr><td>{{ form_row(form.number, {'attr': 'value': commande.number} ) }}</td></tr>
<tr><td>{{ form_row(form.date, {'attr': 'value': commande.date} ) }}</td>

<td><button type="submit" name="btn">update</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `{'attr': 'value': commande.id}` this isn't a valid array. Should be `{'attr': {'value': commande.id}}`

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work like that.

Comment: From a quick look, this seems like a case of embedding a collection of forms. There is a relevant example on the documentation. Check https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Answer (score 1):

Forms are sometimes smart and know they have been rendered.

Workaround:

```
{% set output_id = form_row(form.id, {'attr': 'value': commande.id}) %}
{{ output_id }}
```

and later on you can access it again:

```
{{ output_id }}
```

You can also do this for more than a form row (or for adding markup):

```
{% set output %}
  {{ form_row(form.id) }}
  {{ form_row(form.number) }}
  {{ form_row(form.date) }}
{% endset %}

{{ output }}
```

(Alternatively, you can probably set the `rendered` attribute to false or something, but to be honest, that seems worse to me than capturing the output).